# HTML table: second row showing beside the first one, not below

Tags: html, html-table, row

Why  is the second row showing inline with the first row and not below like the others? Here's the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/jdelva/9MfGf/4/

```
<body>
<table id="mitabla" >
    <caption>
        <span class="titulo">Tabla de posiciones campeonato nacional</span>
    </caption>
    <tr class="encabezado">
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> #</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> /\</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="8"> Equipo</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> PJ</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> PG</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> PE</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> PP</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> GF</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> GC</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> DG</th>
        <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> Pt</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="equipo">
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="equipo">
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="equipo">
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>



</table>
</body>
```

PS: sorry for the spanish I was too lazy to translate it, but I mean, those words aren't the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try this  insert empty row after first row

```
<body>
<table id="mitabla" >
<caption>
    <span class="titulo">Tabla de posiciones campeonato nacional</span>
</caption>
<tr class="encabezado">
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> #</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> /\</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="8"> Equipo</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> PJ</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> PG</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> PE</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> PP</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> GF</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> GC</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> DG</th>
    <th rowspan="2" colspan="2"> Pt</th>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr class="equipo">
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="equipo">
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="equipo">
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your empty row is not W3C compliant.

Comment: The question is why would I have to insert an empty row?

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `rowspan="2"` and your second row is on the right place.

Comment: Can you tell me why rowspan="2" affected the second row?  Maybe I have a bad perception of how it works